# Не могу додуматься как написать функцию которая преобразует входной список след. образом

Tags: python

Есть список `[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4]`
На выходе надо получить  `[[1, 1], [2], [3,3], [2, 2], [4]`
То есть добавлять надо список состоящий из вот таких одинаковых, последовательно идущих чисел.
Сижу уже долго, пытался рекурсией запилить, не вышло че т. Буду благодарен за наводку или псевдокод

P.S. Не судите строго:) Возможно тут полный бред написан, но у меня голова уже не работает и с рекурсией я не особо писал. Здесь я вместо выхода из рекурсии подумал обернуть все в try/except, но что то не так пошло. Данная шляпа возвращает None

```
result = []
def split(array: list):
    try:
        partition = []
        current_elem = array.pop(0)
        partition.append(current_elem)

        for elem in array:
            if elem == current_elem:
                partition.append(elem)
            else:
                result.append(partition)
                start_idx = array.index(elem)
                split(array[:start_idx])
    except IndexError as e:
        return result
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите в вопрос вашу попытку. Возможно, её нужно лишь слегка доработать. Это сэкономит ваше время и время отвечающих

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необязательно рекурсией, то можно через `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4]
out = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(lst)]
print(out)
```

```
[[1, 1], [2], [3, 3], [2, 2], [4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так преобразовать список в список списков повторений

```
res = []
def uniq(array):
    part = [array[0]]
    current = array.pop(0)
    if len(array) == 0:
        res.append(part)
    iter = 0
    for elem in array:
        if elem == current:
            part.append(elem)
            iter += 1
            if len(array) == iter:
                res.append(part)
        else:
            res.append(part)
            uniq(array[iter:])
            break
uniq(lst)
print(res)
```

Comment: [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3] --> [[1, 1], [2], [3], [4], [2]] 
Остаток почему то не берет

Comment: @daniskzn Поправил

Answer (score 0):

Через простой цикл:

```
items = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4]
new_items = [[items[0]]]
for i in range(1, len(items)):
    x = items[i]
    sub = new_items[-1]
    if x in sub:
        sub.append(x)
    else:
        new_items.append([x])

print(new_items)
# [[1, 1], [2], [3, 3], [2, 2], [4]]
```